# Are there any eruvs that include both sides of a US Interstate Highway?

Tags: shabbat, geography, eruv-chatzerot

Are there any eruvs that include both sides of a US Interstate Highway?

I assumed this was halachically and/or logistically impossible. Is that correct? Can anyone prove this wrong by (groan) construction?

Comment: Why would you think it's impossible? That may affect the validity of answers, including the answer I gave (and you accepted). For example, I-170, like all three-digit interstates that start with an odd number, is a spur; thus, it's not as used as, e.g., I-70. Moreover, I-170 in the _eruv_ is (I think) never at grade except to briefly cross from below grade to above grade. Does either of those considerations affect your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [St. Louis [Missouri] Community Eruv](http://www.stleruv.org) includes portions of either side of [Interstate 170](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_170).

Answer (score 5):

[The Center City [of Philadelphia, Penna.] Eruv](http://centercityeruv.org/) includes portions of either side of [Interstate 676](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_676) and, [seemingly](http://centercityeruv.org/Map.htm), [Interstate 95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_95_in_Pennsylvania). (Caveat lector: I know nothing about the validity of this *eruv*.)

Answer (score 3):

The Far Rockaway/Lawrence, NY Eruv http://www.shaaray-tefilah.org/eruv.pdf contains the route of I-878. However they did build a Mechitza on the Far Rockaway side of the road for those in FR who are Machmir.